# Handling multiple objects in a single function

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file with similar data set but different objects.

```
{
    "AP": [{
            "name": "Autogen Program"
        }, {
            "status": "Completed"
        }, {
            "start": "2014-05-05"
        }, {
            "end": "2014-05-05"
        }],
    "BP": [{
            "name": "Backend Program"
        }, {
            "status": "In Progress"
        }, {
            "start": "2014-05-05"
        }, {
            "end": ""
        }],
    "AP": [{
            "name": "Capital Program"
        }, {
            "status": "Pending"
        }, {
            "start": ""
        }, {
            "end": ""
    }]
}
```

I have a function to call each individually.

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json', function(statusDataSet) {
        $.each(statusDataSet.AP, function(i, f) {
            var color;
            switch(f.status) {
                case "In Progress":
                    color = "yellow";
                    break;
                case "Pending": 
                    color = "red";
                    break;
                case "Completed": 
                    color = "green";
                    break;
            }

            $("#stat1").append(f.value).css('background-color', color);
        });
    });
});
```

Is it possible to call all the status value in a single function? Or, how to keep color case in separate function so that I can call that function instead of writing the color switch case for each function?

Something like this :--

```
$("#stat1").append(AP.status).css('background-color', color);
$("#stat2").append(BP.status).css('background-color', color);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in following [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principles, I suggest creating a wrapper function that will handle all types, and pass an argument to indicate the type to process, and another to pass the element to append to.

Also changed the switch to a simple object mapper, the reason being because the logic is the same in each case, a switch isn't really necessary.

```
function myCall(type, statElement){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json', function(statusDataSet) {
        $.each(statusDataSet[type], function(i, f) {
            var colorMap = {
                "In Progress" : "yellow",
                "Pending"     : "red",
                "Completed"   : "green"
            };

            statElement.append(
                $('<span />', { text : f.value })
                    .css('background-color', colorMap[f.status]);
            );
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
myCall('AP', $('#stat1'));
myCall('BP', $('#stat2'));
```

Comment: So should I call $(function() {

    #test1 = myCall('AP');
    #test2 = myCall('AP');
 });

Comment: I just made an edit for that - see update. Simply pass it as another argument e.g. `myCall('AP', $('#stat1'));`.

Comment: It works good but only problem is that everytime it is taking last value .I tried to call it in follwoing manner `$(function() {

var test1 = myCall('AP', $('#stat1'));
var test2 = myCall('BP', $('#stat2'));

 });`  and again called in HTML as `  <form action="status1.asp">
   <td>
    <textarea readonly style="overflow:hidden" id="test1" cols="12" rows="1" autofocus ></textarea>
   </td>
  </form>
  <form action="status2.asp">
   <td>
     <textarea readonly style="overflow:hidden" id="test2" cols="12" rows="1" autofocus ></textarea>
   </td>
  </form>`

Comment: See my new edit - that will work for appending to a div from example and having child spans each with their own background color. Are you trying to append to a textarea? If so, they can't have child elements. Use a div or some other element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 var color = {"In Progress": "yellow", "Pending": "red", "Completed": "green"};
 $("#stat2").append(BP.status).css('background-color', color[BP.status]);
```

For complete loop, I would recommend following

```
 var color = {"In Progress": "yellow", "Pending": "red", "Completed": "green"};
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json', function(statusDataSet) {
    $.each(statusDataSet.AP, function(i, f) {
        if (f.status != undefined) {     // New Code after edit
             $("#stat1").append(f.status).css('background-color', color[f.status]);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Please let me know if you require help in understanding any part of the solution or you face any issue with it.

Also, I would recommend changing your data format to following, which is much easier to interpret:

```
{
"AP": {"name": "Autogen Program",
        "status": "Completed",
        "start": "2014-05-05",
        "end": "2014-05-05"
    },
"BP": {
        "name": "Backend Program",
        "status": "In Progress",
        "start": "2014-05-05",
        "end": ""
    }
}
```

If you are using my suggested format, the function will becoming something like this:

```
 var color = {"In Progress": "yellow", "Pending": "red", "Completed": "green"};
 $(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json', function(index, statusDataSet) {
    $("#stat1").append(statusDataSet.status).css('background-color', color[statusDataSet.status]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I cannot modify the JSON format as that is what is being shared by the system.I tried using the function like      $(function() {
 
   var color = {"In Progress": "yellow", "Pending": "red", "Completed": "green"}; 
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/GChartServlet/data1.json', function(index, statusDataSet) {
    $.each(statusDataSet, function(i, f) {
        $("#stat1").append(f.status).css('background-color', color[f.status]);
    });
  });
}); But it is not helping

Comment: please tell me what error it is giving and i'll be able to help you out. As for the change of format, it was purely a suggestion...

Comment: I have some more changes, please try, I think the format was not suited for the solution I gave. Try placing the new changes, and it should work...

Comment: Hi, It works fine but in this way I will have to write sep function for each status .I was looking for a solution where I can pull values for all status in single function.

Comment: You can use the method suggested by @MrCode, and inside the function use my code, i believe ur problem will be solved...

Comment: Tried it but since I am new to HTML coding I am unable to pull the value from function to a variable .

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't have access to my laptop right now and won't be able to help you any further...

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function like:

```
      function getColorForStatus(status) {
        var color;
        switch(status) {
            case "In Progress":
                color = "yellow";
                break;
            case "Pending": 
                color = "red";
                break;
            case "Completed": 
                color = "green";
                break;
        }
        return color;
    }
```